# What is the meaning of "as acute as" in this term?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Is the meaning of the following term different when "as acute as" is deleted?

```
I suffered a dislocation as acute as when I arrived in this country.
```

( I have seen "as acute", but I have not seen "as acute as" somewhere)

Comment: Your quote has **acute**, but the question has **cute**.  These are different words.  Which one is are you asking about?  I think you mean **acute**.

Comment: The phrase is **as ACUTE as** not **as cute as**.  Omitting the phrase completely changes the sense of the sentence.

Comment: @RonaldSole Thank You. Yes That was "acute".  So this is the second time that he/she  sufferes dislocation. Is it true?  (The first time: "when he/she arives in that country" the second time is "when he/she says that sentence")

Comment: @JoJomax Yes, the sentence is comparing a present dislocation (or sense of dislocation) with that felt on the speaker's arrival in the country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author has recently suffered a "dislocation" (and I think this is a psychological dislocation, not a dislocation of the hip, for example).

> Dislocation is identified psychologically as a “lack of attachment, belonging, identity, meaning, [and] purpose”  ([source](https://www.graniterecoverycenters.com/resources/understanding-the-dislocation-theory-of-addiction/))

To tell you how acute this recent dislocation was, they compare it to a dislocation they suffered previously. I understand that the "dislocation suffered when she arrived in the country" was a very acute dislocation.

> I suffered a dislocation.  This dislocation was as acute as the dislocation that I suffered when I arrived in the country".

"Acute" in this sense means "sudden and severe"